# How meanings differ if you put 'always' in: "{1}, seat belts {2} should {3} be {4} used {5}."

Tags: sentence-meaning, adverb-placement

Possible positions:

1. **Always**, seat belts should be used.
2. Seat belts **always** should be used.
3. Seat belts should **always** be used.
4. Seat belts should be **always** used.
5. Seat belts should be used **always**.

Questions:

1. Are the above sentences correct?
2. If so, how do they differ in terms of meaning?

Comment: Without any additional context, only sentences 3 and 5 sound ok, the others sound unnecessarily awkward. But in general, word order changes like this are made to change emphasis, express different moods, etc. Exactly which nuance each word order expresses would depend on the context around it. With these short sentences and no context, I can say that 3 seems like a generic statement (typical word order), 5 seems to emphasize the "always", whereas the others don't seem to have any reason for the change in word order, so just seem weird.

Comment: @filistinist,  that is a complete answer, so should be written as an answer and not posted as a comment.  I've converted it to a community wiki below.  If you post your own answer I'll delete my community wiki answer.

Comment: @JamesK, I was hoping the OP might have some additional context so I could answer their specific question instead of just posting a general comment on the topic. But thank you for posting to the wiki, I appreciate you doing this. If the OP won't have any additional details, it will have to do as an answer.

Comment: Version #3 is the ***only*** "standard" position for adverbial ***always***. There's no universally-recognised significance to placing it anywhere else, so all we can really say is that if a competent native speaker *did* use "non-standard" adverb placement here, the audience / readers would tend to assume he meant something at least ***slightly*** different to the "normal" sense. Exactly what assumptions one might make would depend on the ***exact*** context - but very likely if there were multiplel addressees, they wouldn't all agree on what ***specific*** different meaning was intended.

Comment: @filistinist,  thank you for your kind response. I was just wondering the most natural position to put 'always' in the sentence whose structure is like the example above, and also wanted to know what kinds of nuances can be made by changing its position. I saw the context is important in this case.

Comment: @jmoreno Thanks for pointing it out. That was just a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to give a comprehensive answer to this as in speech the intonation might make them sound appropriate whereas on the page they seem strange.

> Always, seat belts should be used.

That sounds a bit odd unless you heavily stress *Always*. Note though that if you replace *always* with *on all occasions* it would be fine.

> Seat belts always should be used.

That would strike the listener as incomplete as they would be expecting some contrasting phrase like *never new* to follow.

> Seat belts should always be used.

Yes, that sounds natural

> Seat belts should be always used.

this is similar to your second example, we are left hanging waiting for the contrasting phrase.

> Seat belts should be used always.

That is OK but not quite as good as the third one. Again it would be fine if you replace *always* with *on all occasions*.

Comment: Thank you, that is comprehensive and helps a lot. I've tried to make examples of #2 and #4 given your answer. For #2: Seat belts always should not be used. (meaning that none of the time, seat belts should not be used) For #4: Seat belts should be always used, not put aside. (emphasizing that they shouldn’t be put aside and should be used instead.) Do these examples make sense?

Comment: Your new #4 is OK but #2 is not correct/